# iOS : Copy selected row from Table to an Array:

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Alright, I'm at a wall.  I'm trying to copy the SELECTED ROW from a Table View and add the contents to an ARRAY.

I tried this, but to no avail:

```
    [self.templist addObject:[self.songsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Any thoughs would be appreciated.  Above, I tried to add the row to an array called templist.   But, no luck.

Thanks,

Comment: Define "no luck". Also, split up the line. Make sure the result of `[self.songsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` gives you the expected value. Then make sure none of the ivars behind these properties are `nil`.

Comment: @user1345470  your templist array alloc or init first and after try .

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'd define "no luck" as spending a couple of hours trying different methods parsed together from various answers on multiple questions.  I'll follow up on your suggestion because, honestly, I do not have any idea what value the indexPath.row returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you actually want to copy..? do you mean a `tableViewCell` ...

if its a `tableViewCell` then its an easytask..

youcan use following line:

```
[NSIndexPath  *index= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];  // Suppose cell no 3 in section 0

UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableName cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];

[yourArray addObject:myCell];
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll give it a shot.  I was under the impression a ROW had many different cells with different values, so I was hoping to just copy the entire row like you would in Excel, and just paste it.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableArray * templist=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSLog(@"%@",templist);

[templist addObject:[self.songlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSLog(@"%@",templist);
```

Try to use NsMutable array...

Comment: downvoter why downvoting me...

Comment: I'm not the down voter but I think your last log should print `templist`, too.

Comment: @HAS sory it was my silly mistake check my update now...

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that s/he didn't alloc omit the array (which is a property btw ;) not a local variable) but that's the last thing I'd recommend ;) you can lazily instantiate it there where you now create it and I'll +1 ya ;)

Comment: i am just telling him follow that way.

Comment: I just think that he's a very beginner since he asks such a trivial question and will copy&paste it and after that complain that it won't work ;)